# WikiToXhtmlMigrator in Confluence

Tags: java, xhtml, confluence, wiki-markup

I have been trying to use this class from tha JAVA API  (https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/5.3.1/index.html?com/atlassian/confluence/), but I'm struggling because of the lack f proper documentation.  My aim is to convert from a wiki markup format to the xhtml that Confluence uses:

Here is my code till now:

```
package org.myorg;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;

    import com.atlassian.renderer.RenderContext;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.migration.WikiToXhtmlMigrator;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.ConversionContext;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.DefaultConversionContext;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.storage.pagelayouts.StoragePageLayoutMarshaller;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.xhtml.api.MacroDefinition;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.storage.macro.*;


    import com.atlassian.renderer.RendererConfiguration;
    import com.atlassian.renderer.links.LinkRenderer;
    import com.atlassian.renderer.v2.V2LinkRenderer;
    import com.atlassian.renderer.embedded.EmbeddedResourceRenderer;
    import com.atlassian.renderer.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedResourceRenderer;
    import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.migration.ErrorReportingV2Renderer;

    import com.atlassian.renderer.v2.V2Renderer;

    import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.storage.macro.StorageMacroV2Marshaller;

    import com.atlassian.renderer.v2.components.RendererComponent;



    public class Wiki2xhtml {

    public static  class Rend implements RendererConfiguration
    {
         public String  getCharacterEncoding() 
         {
             return new String("UTF-8");
             //Will return the character encoding for the current application.

         }

         public String  getWebAppContextPath()
         {

             return "";

             //Returns the context path of the running web application.
         }
         public boolean isAllowCamelCase()
         {
             return true;
             //If this method returns true then camelCase links will be allowed and generated.
         }
         public boolean isNofollowExternalLinks() 
         {
             return false;
             //If this method returns true then external links will be generated with the rel=nofollow attribute.
         }
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\arenu.CORP\\Desktop\\docs\\Engineering\\markupFile"));
        String wikiContent = new String();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            wikiContent = wikiContent + line;
        }

        /*
        public WikiToXhtmlMigrator(com.atlassian.renderer.RendererConfiguration rendererConfiguration,
                com.atlassian.renderer.links.LinkRenderer defaultLinkRenderer,
                com.atlassian.renderer.embedded.EmbeddedResourceRenderer defaultEmbeddedRenderer,
                ErrorReportingV2Renderer renderer)
        */
        RenderContext rE = new RenderContext();
        DefaultConversionContext dCE = new DefaultConversionContext(rE);

        RendererConfiguration rC = new Rend();
        LinkRenderer dLC = new V2LinkRenderer(); 
        EmbeddedResourceRenderer dER = new DefaultEmbeddedResourceRenderer();


        //ErrorReportingV2Renderer(java.util.List<com.atlassian.renderer.v2.components.RendererComponent> components, Marshaller<MacroDefinition> wikiMarkupMacroMarshaller) 

        List<RendererComponent> rCList = new ArrayList<RendererComponent> ();

        MacroDefinition mD = new MacroDefinition();

        ErrorReportingV2Renderer renderer = new ErrorReportingV2Renderer(rCList, whatshouldcomehere) ;

        WikiToXhtmlMigrator migr = new WikiToXhtmlMigrator(rC,dLC,dER,vR);
        //String migrated = new String();
        //migrated = migrate(java.lang.String wiki, com.atlassian.renderer.RenderContext context, java.util.List<java.lang.RuntimeException> exceptions) 
        //migrated = migrate(java.lang.String wiki, ConversionContext conversionContext) 
        String migrated = (migr.migrate(wikiContent, dCE)).getContent();

        System.out.println(migrated);

    }

}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, and I have no clue as to what each part means because of the abstract way in which everything is defined in the documentation.

Can someone help me with how to initialize `ErrorReportingV2Renderer` renderer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get hold of the Confluence source code - buy a 10 user/$10 license if you don;'t already have it. Then you'll be able to search the best documentation there is -- *the source code*

Both `wikiToXhtmlMigrator` and `migrationRenderer` are defined as beans in `ContextMigrationRenderer.xml`

Atlassian are accessing the using this to access their `WikiToXhtmlMigrator`:

```
ExceptionTolerantMigrator wikiToXhtmlMigrator = (ExceptionTolerantMigrator) ContainerManager.getComponent("wikiToXhtmlMigrator");
```

You should be able to access `ErrorReportingV2Renderer` using:

```
ExceptionTolerantMigrator wikiToXhtmlMigrator = (ExceptionTolerantMigrator) ContainerManager.getComponent("migrationRenderer");
```